# Display total weight in Magento cart

Tags: php, magento

I use the  below code to get the total weight of products in cart.
However I want to call the weight value from /template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml

So I'm a bit lost where to place the below code in order to call it from the above template.

```
$items = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems();

$weight = 0;
foreach($items as $item) {
    $weight += ($item->getWeight() * $item->getQty()) ;
}

echo $weight;
```

Comment: lets check the quote first, is your quote empty or not? try to count($items);

Comment: lets clarify - `$weight` is calculated correctly but u want to pass value to template?

Comment: You can put it in your block class. check in your template file echo get_class($this);

Comment: Yes, $weight is carculated in the right way. I just want to know where to place a function like:

`function getCartWeight(){
 $items = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems();
 $weight = 0;
 foreach($items as $item) {
     $weight += ($item->getWeight() * $item->getQty()) ;
 }
 return $weight;
}`

And how to access it in the template.

Comment: Assuming you want to display the weight of all the product in cart before the cart totals section in the cart page, try adding the below code in /template/checkout/cart.phtml before `<div class="totals">` `<?php $weight = 0;
        foreach($this->getItems() as $_item):
             $weight += ($_item->getWeight() * $_item->getQty());
        endforeach;
        echo $weight; ?>`

Comment: Did you solve...?